# Extract substring after '-' character in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using the following formula to extract the substring `venue01` from column C, the problem is that when value string in column C is shorter it only extracts the value 1 I need it to extract anything straight after the `-` (dash) no matter the length of the value text in column c

```
={"VenueID";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",RIGHT(C2:C,SEARCH("-",C2:C)-21)))}
```

[image]

Comment: Will adding a `len()` instead of 21 work? `={"VenueID";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",RIGHT(C2:C,SEARCH("-",C2:C)-LEN(C2:C))))}`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is a much simpler solution using regular expressions.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".*-(.*)")
```

In case you are no familiar with [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) what this means is, get me every string of characters (`(.*)`) after a dash (`-`).

#### Example

[image: Sample of RegExtract]

#### Reference

- [`REGEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)
- [Test regular expressions](https://regexr.com/)
- [Cheat sheet for regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet)

Comment: Would you be able to share the solution for extracting a string *before* instead of after?

Comment: > Would you be able to share the solution for extracting a string before instead of after? – 

Just change the capturing group to the first wildcard rather than the second i.e. `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.*)-.*")`

Answer (score 7):

To answer bomberjackets question in the comment of Raserhin:

To select the part of the string before the "-"

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.*)-.*")
```

**EXAMPLE**

[example of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNzVP.png)

Comment: Thank you @Rousseau Nutter. In my case I was looking for a parentheses. So to all those looking to replace the dash with some other indicator, you may need to escape your dividing indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to your original formula. I think if you'd use RIGHT and inside it reverse the order of the string with ARRAY then that may work.

```
=Right(A1,FIND("-",JOIN("",ARRAYFORMULA(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1))))-1)
```

[image]

- It takes string from the right side up to X number of characters.
- Number of character is fetched from reversing the text, then finding
  the dash "-".
- It adds one more +1 of the text as it will take out so it accounts
  for the dash itself, if no +1 is added, it will show the     dash on
  the     extracted string.

The REGEX on the other answer works great too, however, you can control a number of character to over or under trim. E.g. if there is a space after the dash and you would like to always account for one more char.